# Not able to persist data using spring managed EntityManager

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa

I need your help again, I am trying to integrate Hibernate + Spring in my standalone java application but the database operations are not working, however the entitymanager is injected which I verified by debugging, so I am not sure what is missing in my code/configuration, I did some research by googling but didnt find something which solves my issue. So I am posting my code/configuration so that somebody can help me get out of this.

entity class:

```
      package com.entity;

      import javax.persistence.Column;
      import javax.persistence.Entity;
      import javax.persistence.GeneratedValue;
      import javax.persistence.GenerationType;
      import javax.persistence.Id;
      import javax.persistence.Table;

      @Entity
      @Table(name = "employee")
      public class Employee {

               @Id
               @GeneratedValue(strategy =  GenerationType.AUTO)
               @Column(name = "EMP_ID")
               private Integer empoyeeId;

               @Column(name = "EMP_NAME")
               private String employeeName;

               public Integer getEmpoyeeId() {
                     return this.empoyeeId;
               }

               public void setEmpoyeeId(Integer empoyeeId) {
                     this.empoyeeId = empoyeeId;
               }

               public String getEmployeeName() {
                     return this.employeeName;
               }

               public void setEmployeeName(String employeeName) {
                   this.employeeName = employeeName;
               }
       }
```

The dao class

```
  package com.dao.impl;

  import javax.persistence.EntityManager;

  import com.dao.IEmployeeDao;
  import com.entity.Employee;

  public class EmployeeDao implements IEmployeeDao {

        private static final Logger LOGGER = 
                  LogManager.getLogger(EmployeeDao.class);

        @PersistenceContext(unitName = "testPU")
        private EntityManager em;

        @Override
        public Employee create(Employee aEmployee) {
           return this.em.merge(aEmployee);
        }

        @Override
        public Employee fetchEmployeeById(Integer aEmployeeId) {
         return this.em.find(Employee.class, aEmployeeId);
        }
  }
```

the main class :

```
    package com.client;

    import org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager;
    import org.apache.logging.log4j.Logger;
    import org.springframework.beans.BeansException;
    import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
    import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

    import com.dao.IEmployeeDao;
    import com.entity.Employee;

    public class Client {
           private static final Logger LOGGER = LogManager.getLogger(Client.class);

           public static void main(String[] args) throws BeansException, 
                   Exception {
                   ApplicationContext applicationContext = new 
                   ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("applicationcontext.xml");
                   LOGGER.info("client invoked");
                   IEmployeeDao employeeDao =  
                   (IEmployeeDao)applicationContext.getBean("employeeDao");
                   Employee employee = new Employee();
                   employee.setEmployeeName("Suraj Kumar");
                   employee = employeeDao.create(employee);
                   employee =                        
                   employeeDao.fetchEmployeeById(employee.getEmpoyeeId());  
                   //getting null pointer here as employee is null

                   //       EntityManagerFactory emf = 
                           Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("testPU");
                  //        EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
                  //        em.getTransaction().begin();
                  //        EmployeeDao employeeDao = new EmployeeDao();
                  //        employeeDao.setEm(em);
                  //        Employee employee = new Employee();
                  //        employee.setEmployeeName("Suraj Kumar");
                  //        employee = employeeDao.create(employee);
                  //        employee = 
                    employeeDao.fetchEmployeeById(employee.getEmpoyeeId());
                  //        em.getTransaction().commit();
                  //        em.close();
                  //        emf.close();
          }
     }
```

with the above client code I am getting null pointer exception when trying to fetch employee by id as the employee returned by the call to create is returning null which asserts that the record was not persisted.

However when I turn off spring by commenting uncommented code above and uncommenting the ones which are commented now i.e when I am only using hibernate without spring everything works fine. I have provided the configuration files below.

applicationcontext.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
        http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.5.xsd ">
    <import resource="aspects.xml"/>

        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.support.
                     PersistenceAnnotationBeanPostProcessor"/>

        <bean id="myEmf" 
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean">
            <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="testPU"/>
        </bean>

        <bean id="employeeDao" class="com.dao.impl.EmployeeDao" />

    </beans>
```

persistence.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
   <persistence xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence

   http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"
          version="2.0">
   <persistence-unit name="testPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
   <provider>org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence</provider>
   <class>com.entity.Employee</class>
   <exclude-unlisted-classes>true</exclude-unlisted-classes>
   <properties>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.url" 
                value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" 
                value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>

      <property name="hibernate.dialect" 
                value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="user"/>
      <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value="password"/>
      <property name="hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
      </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
  </persistence>
```

I am also using aspects but I have not posted the code as I am not sure if its relevant as I tried by turning off aspects even then I am facing this issue, just one strange thing happens on turning off aspects that is instead of getting a null pointer exception I get another exception from inside the find method of EntityManager class which indicates that in this case the create method of dao class does not return null.

Could somebody please help me with it ?

Comment: guys could anybody help please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems your transaction is not being commited.

Try adding @Transactional to your methods in the EmployeeDao class or, even better, create a Service layer to handle transactions and annotate their methods whit @Transactional

Comment: I added @Transactional only on the create method of my dao class as the one to fetch is read only method, I am still getting null pointer exceptio

Comment: just one more point, i just read that we got to use <tx:annotation-driven/> tag in order to assist spring in identifying annotation based aops, but in that case I get an exception with message java.lang.IllegalStateException: AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource is only available on Java 1.5 and higher,  I am using java 7, however I am still working with spring-2.5.5, could that be the reason for this exception, probably I need to increase the spring version to have support for java 7, I am not sure if I am wandering in the right direction ?

Comment: it worked, the methods not running inside the transaction was a problem. there were some other issues because of which i was facing issues, but for the operations to not work the main reason was missing transactional behvaiour. so I marked your answer as accepted